# How to create image mosaic like Lego app?

Tags: iphone, ios4, lego-mindstorms

I'm trying to play around with turning an image into mosaic bricks like the [Lego Photo](http://itunes.apple.com/au/app/lego-photo/id347363502?mt=8) app.

How is it done, and where can I find more info?

Comment: Could you possibly narrow this question down a bit? Have you tried any experimenting on your own? This is rather broad for Stack Overflow and might be closed without additional context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically need to iterate through the pixels, to calculate the average colour for say every 4x4 block of pixels. Once you have this average colour, you 'round' it to the nearest colour that you can use in your mosaic. I don't know the specifics of it but this [sample code](http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/05/create-mosaic-with-your-image-part-1.html) does exactly what you want.